# Adding pictures to a table

Tags: tables

I would like to add pictures to that table. How could I do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}

  \hline
  Titre & Type & Composition & Dimensions & Prix \\
  \hline
  Title & Peinture & 80 x 120 cm & Acrylique, feutre, fusain & 80 \\
   \hline
   Title & Sculpture & 80 x 100 cm & 2.3 & 150 \\
\hline
     Title & Sculpture & 80 x 100 cm & 2.3 & 150 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\includegraphics` from the [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package. You probably also want to set a width or height on the image (if you set only one then the aspect ratio will be preserved). Doing this produces:

[image]

This said, for reasons outlined in the manual for the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package, I recommend dropping the vertical lines and using `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` from [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). I think that this results is much better looking output:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Titre & Type & Composition & Dimensions & Prix &Picture \\
  \hline
  Title & Peinture & 80 x 120 cm & Acrylique, feutre, fusain & 80
                  &\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-a} \\
   \hline
   Title & Sculpture & 80 x 100 cm & 2.3 & 150
                  &\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-b} \\
\hline
     Title & Sculpture & 80 x 100 cm & 2.3 & 150
                  &\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-b} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*6c}\toprule
  Titre & Type & Composition & Dimensions & Prix &Picture \\\midrule
  Title & Peinture & 80 x 120 cm & Acrylique, feutre, fusain & 80
                  &\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-a} \\
   Title & Sculpture & 80 x 100 cm & 2.3 & 150
                  &\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-b} \\
     Title & Sculpture & 80 x 100 cm & 2.3 & 150
                  &\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-b} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```